# probability of hamlet appearing when the $26$ letters on a keyboard are typed exactly once in random order

Tags: probability

I saw the answers of this question, but I didn't understand how to choose hamlet from $26$ letters. I understood the denominator $26!$, but I didn't understand the calculations of numerator $20!\cdot21$

Why not say that the numerator is $26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24 \cdot 23 \cdot 22 \cdot 21$?

> A monkey at a typewriter types each of the $26$ letters of the alphabet exactly once, the order being random.
>
> 1. What is the probability that the word Hamlet appears somewhere in the string of letters?
> 2. How many independent monkey typists would you need in order that the
>    probability that the word appears is at least $.90$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For problem $1$:

Of the $26!$ permutations of the $26$ letters, let $x_N$ be the number of "hamlet-containing" permutations  such that the letter "h" is at position $N$.

Then $x_N=20!\;\,$if $1 \le N \le 21,\;$and $x_N = 0\;\,$if $N > 21$.

Hence, the total number of hamlet-containing permutations is
$$x_1 + \cdots + x_{21} = (21)20!$$

Thus, the probability that a random permutation of the $26$ letters is hamlet-containing is
$$p = \frac{(21)20!}{26!}$$
For problem $2$:

The probability that $M$ monkeys all fail to get "hamlet" is
$(1-p)^M$, where 
$$p = \frac{(21)20!}{26!}$$
So you need solve the equation 
$$(1-p)^M=\frac{1}{10}$$
for $M$, and take the ceiling of the result.

If you work it out correctly, in order to get "hamlet" with probability at least $.90$, you would need at least $18,175,685$ monkeys.

Comment: Why not say that the numerator is 26⋅25⋅24⋅23⋅22⋅21?

Comment: By what logic would you get that numerator?

Comment: why did you delete the 5 possibilities 26*25*24*22 @quasi

Comment: If he lettter "h" appears in position greater than $21$, there's not enough space for "hamlet".

Comment: because you know the string hamlet not choose randomly

Comment: "hamlet" has $6$ characters, so if it occurs, it must start in one of the positions $1$ through $21$, otherwise there's not enough space (left-to-right). The other $20$ characters can be placed in the remaining $20$ positions in arbitrary order (which explains the factor of $20!$).

Comment: the logic of this solution is not obvious for me

Comment: you mean if multiply 26*25*24*23*22*21 there is no space for halmet string

Comment: No, I mean if "h" appears in position $22$ or more, then "hamlet" string is impossible.

Comment: To understand the logic of the solution, let's take a simple case . . . How many permutations have "hamlet" with the letter "h" in position $1$?

Comment: I understood what you said but my query about why not  multiply 26*25*24*23*22*21

Comment: That could be the denominator (after the cancellation).

Comment: if you draw letter 'h' randomly from 26 letters the remaining 25 letter if you draw 'a' randomly the remaining 24 so the ways to draw "ha" 26 *25 way

Comment: Perhaps what you mean is this: The probability $p$ of getting "hamlet" can be expressed as
$$p=\frac{1}{26}\cdot\frac{1}{25}\cdot\frac{1}{24}\cdot\frac{1}{23}\cdot\frac{1}{22}$$
If so, that's correct, and matches the calculation in my answer.

Comment: how the denominator  (after cancellation) the denominator is 26! the monkey typed alphabet a-z randomly for exactly once means 'a' was written once to z but in different order

Comment: The denominator is $26!$ _before_ cancellation. After cancellation, the denominator is $26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22$.

Comment: Note that the problem requires "hamlet" to be written as _consecutive_ letters (i.e., the letter "a" must occur as the next letter to the right of "h").

Comment: no I mean numerator why not (26*25*24*23*22*21/ 26!)

Comment: There's no logic for that.

Comment: So are you placing "h" in one of $26$ positions? And then "a" in one of $25$ positions? etc? If so, that's wrong for several reasons. Firstly, to get hamlet, "h" has only $21$ possible positions, not $26$. Secondly, once "h" is placed in one of the first $21$ positions, to get "hamlet", there is only $1$ possible position for "a", namely, the position immediately to the right of the position where "h" was placed.

Comment: So the numerator is really
$$21\cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot  1\cdot 20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdots 1$$
where the $21$ is the number of choices for the position of "h" and the next $5$ factors of $1$ represent the numbers of choices for "a","m","l","e","t", respectively, and the factors $20,19,18,...1$ represent the number of choices for the remaining $20$ letters.

Comment: why "h" hasn't 26 possible positions?

Comment: If you place "h" in position $26$, how can you have "hamlet"? The letter "a" would have to be in position $27$, but there is no such position.

Comment: Thank you very much but why multiply by 20! it needs the probability of appears string in 26 letter in random order

Comment: you mean that h in $26$ position $(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,h)$  the position $26$  or $(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,h,)$ in postion $25$ or  $(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,h,,)$ in postion $24$ or  $(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,h,,,)$ in postion $23$ or $(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,h,,,,)$ in postion 22 this make "a m l et " no space to be written in consecutive sequence

Comment: After hamlet is placed, there are still $20$ more letters left, and $20$ positions.

Comment: As already discussed, the letter "h" _can't_ be in position $26$.

Comment: you asked me question about logic but I have seen  it now  
To understand the logic of the solution, let's take a simple case . . . How many permutations have "hamlet" with the letter "h" in position 1
? one permutation right ?

Comment: No, 20! permutations. If "h" is in the first position, and you have "hamlet", then the first $6$ positions are forced. But the remaining $20$ letters of the alphabet can be placed in positions $7$ through $26$ in _any_ order, so $20!$ such permutations.

Comment: So if h in position 2 also 20 permutations h is shiftd to position 21 this last position allowed so we multiply 21×20! Right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.